# Mac Preview appends Photo in Tab

Tags: photos, pdf, preview

### Problem

Each time I want to view an image, such as a .png or .jpeg file on my Mac, Preview is opened as my default app for files like these. If Preview is already in use of reading a .pdf at that time, it will automatically append the image to the pdf. When I want to close the photo I automatically close the .pdf as well.

I don't like this behavior. I'd like my photos to be opened in separate tabs each. Please help me with this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**: Open the preview settings and unselect "open all files in the same window".

1. Open the preview app.
2. Hit <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> or click on "preview" in the top menu bar and select "settings"
3. Go to "images"
4. Unselect "open all files in the same window"